# Which vehicles can be destroyed by a predator missile?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I know I can destroy Chopper Gunners, Harriers, Attack Helicopters and Pave Lows with a predator missile. But what about UAV's, Counter-UAV's, Stealth Bombers and AC130's?

Just some moments ago I got pwned by a AC130 and I wanted to destroy it with a predator missile, but it didn't show up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to kill anything except for other Predators, Emergency Airdrops, Stealth Bombers, EMPs and Tactical Nukes, but including AC-130s, using a Predator missile.

The [Predator Missile](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Predator_Missile) article on the [Call of Duty wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com) says:

> To do this, the player should memorize the small icon of where the AC-130 is, when the player pulls out the Killstreak, bank sharply towards its direction and the player should see the AC-130 circling the map. Accelerate towards it to stop its rampage.

Comment: So I can destroy a Care Package delivery helicopter?

Comment: With good timing, sure.

Comment: I do not think you can take out UAVs and Counter UAVs.

Comment: @DarkShiva - According to the wiki, you can.

Comment: @Arda Xi - You would have to be a really really good shot.  At least the AC-130 is a big target.

Comment: @DarkShiva - Never claimed it was easy...

Comment: @Arda Xi - It is also a waste of a predator missle.